# Convert image data to raw bitmap

Tags: cocoa, image, bitmap

In my application I need to convert raw byte data (NSData object) into a raw Bitmap. The system should work with as many formats as possible (32 bit JPG/Tiff but also 24 bit Tiff etc.). So far I was creating and NSImage of the NSData and the converted that into a CGImageRef. I then used CGCreateImageContext to read the raw bitmap data, however, the supported formats of CGCreateImageContext are very limited (eg. 24 bit Tiffs are not supported). Is there any other way to read the actual bitmap of an image without the aid of CGImageContextCreate?